# Points between two location

Tags: android, gps

Im developing an android app for traffic monitoring. I collect traffic info and update n a data base.what i need is when user enter his current location and destination app provide traffic situation between two locations. IS there any way to detect whether the updated traffic locations are between my two points. 
thanks in advance

Comment: If they are on a straight line?

Comment: You need to provide more context and information in order for us to help you. Have you attempted this problem at all?

Comment: no they are not in a straight line.I have tried some other methods to provide the traffic data to users. but i need to know whether google maps have provided such facility.

Answer (score 1):

sure there are many options to do this - I would suggest the following:

assume:

```
 start is S
 destination is D
 point to check ( traffic point ) is P
```

then you calculate the following distances ( with harvesine formula )

```
 SD
 SP
 DP
```

when P is on a straight line between S and D then SD=SP+DP - but as you also want to check for points that are not on that ideal line you will need to check for something like this SD+C>SD+DP
C is a constant ( or constant function/percentage of SD ) to specify a threshold which specifies which points count as between S and D for your application

Answer (score 0):

No, I think this will not work:

You would need the route from start to destination as a list of road polygons.
But this data you will not get from Google, etc. They don't give you the vectors.
Without that you cannot match your traffic data to street polygons.

This can work for OpenStreetmap, because these vectors are open data.

But this all together is a major task...